# When updating value of CheckboxListTile in dynamically bind ListView in flutter its reload whole UI

Tags: flutter

I am try to bind dynamic ListView.builder with child CheckboxListTile . When clicking on check box its reload the whole view and check status of chexkbox is still unchecked.

My code is

```html
<code>

  Widget bindMedium(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    _medium = snapshot.data["data"]["medium"];
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _medium == null ? 0 : _medium.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new CheckboxListTile(
          title: new Text(_medium[index]["medium"]),
          value: _medium[index]["selected"],
          onChanged: (bool newValue) {
            setState(() => _medium[index]["selected"] = newValue);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget bindClass(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    _classes = snapshot.data["data"]["classes"];
    return new Container(
        child: new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _classes == null ? 0 : _classes.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new CheckboxListTile(
          title: new Text(_classes[index]["class"]),
          value: _classes[index]["selected"],
          onChanged: (bool newValue) {
            print("New Value ::" + _classes[index]["selected"].toString());
            _classes[index]["selected"] = true;
          },
        );
      },
    ));
  }

</code>
```

How to update the checked status of check box in flutter.

Comment: You need to call setState in `onChanged` if you want the UI to update.

Comment: Also not sure how your methods are used in build, please post the entire class